# Sidr menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to add the Sidr menu to display a control panel on the left side of [my webapp](http://daviddiliberto-whiteboard.daviddiliberto.nodejitsu.com). I am not very familiar with jQuery (or js programming)but have followed the step by step guide on http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#usage for the "simplest usage" to implement.

I have included the css, links to jquery and the sidr jQuery file and believe i have properly formated my div elements.

It seems when i drop this into my html:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
</script>
```

it breaks all my javascript and my app wont work. What am i missing? Please can anyone check it out and tell me what I may be doing wrong here?

live demo: daviddiliberto-whiteboard.daviddiliberto.nodejitsu.com

Many thanks!!

Comment: Looks like you are including your plugin before jQuery. Try moving that script tag below your jQuery script tag.

Comment: Open the developer tools in Chrome and check console.. It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Adam was right. This is fixed now. Thanks!